# Reduced row echelon basis of weakly holomorphic modular forms have algebraic coefficients?

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

Let $S^{\infty}_{k}(\Gamma_{0}(N))$ be the space of weakly holomorphic modular functions for $\Gamma_{0}(N)$ whose only possible poles lie at the cusp $\infty$ and vanish at all other cusps. There is a "reduced row echelon basis" for this space (see e.g. [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.14403.pdf)) of the form
$$g_{n} = q^{-n} + \sum_{m} b(n, m)q^{m},$$
where $m$ runs through some indexing set.

I am wondering if the $g_{n}$ necessarily have algebraic integer coefficients. A comment in this [overflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432696/congruence-modular-forms-have-a-basis-with-integral-coefficients) references Shimura's well-known text to point out that weak forms should have bases consisting of forms with algebraic coefficients. Does this imply the above reduced echelon basis must also share this property?

Comment: What you ask seems much harder than the linked mathoverflow post

Comment: If I multiply by a sufficiently large power of $\Delta$, I get a cusp form, which is a linear combination of basis elements in $S_{k}(\Gamma_{0}(N), \chi)$. I can choose these to have algebraic coefficients, but that's as far as I can go!